# Cannot use CharSequence or toString() for retrieved Date

Tags: android, simpledateformat

I'm going through the Big Nerd Ranch Guide Android development 2nd edition and I'm currently on the CriminalIntent app.  I'm following the tutorial step by step but there seems to be a bug that developed perhaps due to updates released after the book.  I'm trying to retrieve my `Date` value and set it as text to my button.

The book suggests that I do this: `mDateButton.setText(mCrime.getDate().toString());`

I did that and also tried to wrap it in `CharSequence` as well like this `mDateButton.setText((CharSequence) mCrime.getDate());`, which was suggested when I hit alt-enter.  In either case, this is what I'm getting from the stacktrace:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.jadecondos.criminalintent/com.example.jadecondos.criminalintent.CrimeActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.Date cannot be cast to java.lang.CharSequence
             at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2665)
             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
             at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
             at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
          Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.Date cannot be cast to java.lang.CharSequence
             at com.example.jadecondos.criminalintent.CrimeFragment.onCreateView(CrimeFragment.java:54)
```

I tried going through the book if I missed something but no.  I couldn't find relevant questions on StackOverflow either.  I appreciate all help.

Thanks.

Comment: the exception text is pretty obvious: java.util.Date cannot be cast to java.lang.CharSequence. even tho your IDE suggested it, it doesn't work.

Comment: Any way to fix this?

Comment: well... what's wrong with the line the book suggstes? ;-)

Comment: Same stacktrace.

Comment: impossible. then your problem is in another line.

Comment: I'm just going to clear my caches and clean build.  Maybe its that.  I'll let you know in a minute :)

Comment: is your mCrime object a Date object? or some custom object?

Comment: Yes sir.  That's how I'm able to access the getter method.

Comment: then try String.valueOf(mCrime.getDate) instead of toString.

Comment: Fixed it.  The books suggestion was correct.  The problem was with the IDE acting up.  Thank you @PhilippSander

Comment: And thank you as well @MohammedJunaid

Comment: @OnurOzbek you should try to understand stuff more... don't just do stuff.

Comment: @PhilippSander I appreciate the suggestion but I learn by doing.  I have ADD so its hard for me to focus.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with the IDE.  The book's suggestion is the correct suggestion.  The problem with the IDE was that the computer I'm using kept the previous stacktrace for each new run so even if I fixed the problem in my code, my app will still crash showing the same stacktrace.

How I solved it was going on a better (my own) laptop.

Comment: Thanks for reporting what the problem was; we always appreciate when someone answers their own question. If you think your question and answer can help others, please explain what the problem with the IDE was and how you fixed it. If not, please consider deleting the question (maybe in a couple of days when the kind people commenting have had a chance to see your answer).

Comment: Thanks for tip.  I edited my answer.  If the question is well asked, do you mind upvoting it?